# Azure Api Management Xml schema validation

Tags: xml, azure, xsd, ibm-api-management

Is there a way to validate schema XML request and response with XSD file directly inside Azure API Management? I'm using Azure functions to create response.
Or only way to do so is to use Logic apps, or validate schema inside Azure function?

Answer (score 1):

No you cant perform the validation inside the api management because the policy engine does not support System.Xml.Schemas  namespace. Easiest and cheapest way for this to be done is inside an Azure function.
PS: All the namespace supported  by the policy engine are available at following link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#CLRTypes

Comment: I don't know why, but I can directly use System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet class inside API Management, even when it's not on supported namespaces. Is it cause of some error? Is it safe to use it?

Comment: As you pointed out,  the official document say it is not supported,  so as I suggested in the answer, safest and cheapest way is to use  azure functions