# Parsing XML Request Body in the Azure APIM

Tags: xml, azure, azure-api-management

I am currently working on parsing and validating the XML request body in Azure APIM, so that if something is missing or not valid , we can return the response and do not send the request to the backend.

I am aware that we have Validation Policies for JSON validation , do we have something for XML as well or not ?

If not , how can we achieve the same in Azure APIM . Please sugggest.

Comment: possible same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477171/azure-api-management-xml-schema-validation

Comment: Thank you @silent . I have already checked the above mentioned link . I was just checking if by that time , we have got some new updates in APIM policies.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [silent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1537195/silent). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

As the Policy Engine does not support we cannot perform validation inside the API Management. Rather we can do that by using Azure Function.

Check the [Policy engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#CLRTypes) document for supported namespace.